# running complex commands when using mongo mapper

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongomapper

What's the best practice for acquiring the connection from mongo mapper and run command that aren't encapsulated via mongo mapper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
MongoMapper.database
# or
MyModel.collection
```

Then look to the the [Mongo Ruby driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver/tree/master/lib/mongo) for things you can do.

Note that MongoMapper supports [atomic modifiers](http://mongomapper.com/documentation/plugins/modifiers.html), and you can run [`distinct`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation#Aggregation-Distinct) queries with:

```
MyModel.query.distinct(:field)
```

Comment: `distinct` etc. is properly delegated as of MongoMapper 0.11.1, so you can now do `MyModel.distinct(:field)` ... see [plucky](https://github.com/jnunemaker/plucky/blob/master/lib/plucky/query.rb), MongoMapper's query engine, for more abstractions over the [Ruby driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver/blob/master/lib/mongo/collection.rb).